# Accessing array of ArrayList using Struts 2 iterator tag

Tags: struts2

I having a doubt regarding accessing an array of arraylist in jsp using iterator tag.

In my action class i used the following codes..,

```
ArrayList[] arr= new ArrayList[10]; 

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    arr[i] = new ArrayList<bean>();
} 

while (some conditions) { 
    arr[i].add(new bean(some values)); 
    i++; 
}
```

My question is.. how can i access the arr[0],arr[1]...arr[n] arraylists in iterator..?

The following code is working perfectly.., but please improve it to achieve my result..!

```
<s:iterator value="display.arr[0]">
  ...
</s:iterator>
```

Helps will be appreciated..!

Comment: Improve it how? I thought you said it was working.

Comment: Hello dave..! Thanks for your reply..! I just achieved to access a single index of the array(a[0]).. But what i'm need is to access the whole index of the array using iterator..!                          that is some thing like,                                                                                   `<s:iterator value="display.arr">                          <s:iterator value="display.arr[dynamic index]">
  ...
</s:iterator>                                          </s:iterator>`

Comment: Dynamic index in the sense, it needs to be changed or incremented for the every iteration of the external iterator!

Comment: So iterate over both lists. You can nest iterator tags just like you can nest "for" loops in java.

Comment: I just tried out the following but it did not works..! `<%  for(int i=0;i<count;i++) { %> <s:iterator value="display.arr[<%=i%>]"> ... </s:iterator> <% } %>` I knew this is a foolish approach..! please post me the syntax to achieve it through ITERATOR..! I don't know how to give dynamic value in nested iterators and increment the same..!

Comment: Use the "var" attribute of the outer iterator to define a variable for the "value" attribute of the inner iterator. It's pretty easy.

Comment: hi dave..! It may pretty much easier for experts like you.. But i'm a newbie to Struts frame work.. please just post me the syntax(dynamic values in internal iterator and increment it for every external iteration) for my scenario and help me out in this..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering if you looked at the [iterator tag documention](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/iterator.html) much; there are at least 3-4 ways to go about doing this, including using an immediate list of indexes, using the `"begin"`/`"end"` attributes, using `"var"` to hold the outer item (not strictly necessary, but IMO it's more communicative), etc.

Assume a property named `"s"` in the bean class, which I call `SomeBean`:

```xml
<s:iterator value="displays" var="display">
  <s:iterator value="#display">
    ${s}<br/>
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Using the Java code at the bottom, this produces the following output:

```
Outer: 0, Inner: 0
Outer: 0, Inner: 1
Outer: 0, Inner: 2
Outer: 1, Inner: 0
Outer: 1, Inner: 1
Outer: 1, Inner: 2
Outer: 2, Inner: 0
Outer: 2, Inner: 1
Outer: 2, Inner: 2
```

The complete action driving this code; I just return a new list every time as an example:

```java
public class NestedListsAction extends ActionSupport {

    public List<List<SomeBean>> getDisplays() {
        List<List<SomeBean>> displays = new ArrayList<List<SomeBean>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            List<SomeBean> innerList = new ArrayList<SomeBean>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                innerList.add(new SomeBean(String.format("Outer: %d, Inner: %d", i, j)));
            }
            displays.add(innerList);
        }

        return displays;
    }

    private class SomeBean {
        private String s;

        public SomeBean(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }

        public String getS() {
            return s;
        }
    }

}
```

Note the [SO policy on accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Normally I wouldn't bring it up to a new user, but IMO I expended more effort answering this question than you did researching it, which makes me depressed.